# In a while-loop ValueError, is it possible to jump back to a specific part?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Title isn't too clear, I get that. I have the following code:

```
ore_types = ["Gold", "Mithril", "Adamantite", "Runite"]
def get_ore_amounts():
    ore_amounts = []
    while 1:
        try:
            for ore_type in ore_types:
                ore_amounts.append(int(input("How much " + ore_type + " do you have? ")))
        except ValueError:
            print("It has to be a rounded number, dumbass")
        else: 
            return ore_amounts
```

When input is wrong, it will reset to asking "How much Gold do you have?". I'd rather it re-asks the latest question (Mithil, Adamantite, Runite). Is there an easy way to do this, or am I supposed to dissect the current code?

Comment: `for ...: while ...: try: ... except: ...`? Only `try` the input operation, not the entire loop.

Comment: This just seems to ask the first question and then skips over it, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
ore_types = ["Gold", "Mithril", "Adamantite", "Runite"]
def get_ore_amounts():
    ore_amounts = []
    for ore_type in ore_types:
        while True:
            try:
                value = int(input("How much " + ore_type + " do you have? "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("It has to be a rounded number, dumbass")
        ore_amounts.append(value)
    return ore_amounts
```

It will loop infinitely with the same input message unless the input value will be correct.